# Does Oracle Enterprise Multi-Master Replication negate the need for Data Guard (Active or not)

Tags: oracle

Does Oracle Enterprise Multi-Master Replication negate the need for Data Guard (Active or not)?

If I deployed a 3 member cluster of Oracle Enterprise (on EC2 not RDS) across 3 availability zones in AWS and each is in a multi-master configuration, does this give me the same or better consistency guarantees along with read availability in the event of one or two cluster members going down?  As opposed to a 3 member cluster with 1 master and 2 replicas under Active Data Guard so I can read from 3 but only write to one?

Comment: Logical replication will never reach the performance of a physical standby. A single huge transaction can cause delays for hours.

Comment: Are you talking about using Oracle GoldenGate? That would replace DataGuard, but still works very similarly, reading directly from transaction logs.

Comment: As far as I know, other than GoldenGate there isn't another multi-master architecture that is supported by Oracle. It isn't provided by AWS.